How do I analyze an emitter follower with a capacitive load?
How do I analyze an emitter follower with a capacitor load?
At 7 MHz, a 1 nF capacitor has impedance of 22 Ω.  A simple emitter follower with a 22 Ω Re is easy to analyze:

However, replace that resistor with a 1 nF capacitor, and the circuit's behavior changes radically:

The emitter stays close to the full Vcc the entire time, and almost no current flows through the emitter.
How do I analyze this? That is, how can I predict the emitter voltage or current? How can I model this circuit as something tractable?

Since the transistor is only able to source current from the positive supply, implying current flowing downwards through the capacitor, and since you've provided no way for current to flow upwards through that capacitor, the capacitor can only charge to some positive voltage, and never discharge again.
Therefore, after the first positive peak of the input signal, the capacitor will have charged to:
$$ V_{C2} = V_{SIG(PK)}-V_{BE} = (+12V) - (0.7V) = 11.3V $$
There it will stay, forever.
Sure, the capacitor will discharge a tiny amount between peaks, due to self discharge, or due to leakage current via the base-emitter junction, which now becomes severely reverse biased when base potential falls again. This means that at each new peak, an equally tiny amount of base/collector current will flow to "top up" the capacitor again.
Apart from that, though, collector and base current will remain near zero following that initial input peak, since the transistor's emitter can never fall below +11.3V. It's held there by the capacitor.
You've effectively made a peak-detector. The first peak charges the capacitor, requiring a lot of current, but thereafter almost no current will flow through that capacitor, since it's already charged to +11.3V.
At 7MHz there will be a lot going on besides what I've described above, since there are parasitic capacitances everywhere that become significant at high frequency. In the following example, I've dropped frequency to 1kHz, for a demonstration without such complications.
It might help to provide a way for the capacitor to discharge. That's easy enough, just put a resistor in parallel with it:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With R1 in place, when the input signal falls, the transistor switches off, permitting capacitor C1 to discharge via R1. That's when current is permitted to flow upwards through C1, clockwise around the loop of C1 and R1. Since with the transistor off, those are the only two elements involved, you would expect to see the classic exponential RC discharge curve (between the green markers):

Each new peak of the input, though, recharges the capacitor, as you can see. That requires a small "peak" of non-zero current emerging from Q1's emitter:

There's one more complication that the simulation does not account for, another parasitic effect, which is that the base-emitter junction is a zener diode which will begin to conduct when \$V_{BE}\$ is reversed biased beyond 5V or so. Since the emitter is held at +11.3V, and the base repeatedly falls to −12V, this occurs every cycle, and that would indeed discharge the capacitor.
So, if you built this circuit in real life, you would in fact see the capacitor discharging to perhaps as low as −7V, as the input goes negative in each cycle. That is not shown in your simulation, or mine.

The problem is that you're trying to linearize about a DC bias where the transistor is deep into cutoff, because there's no way for C2 to discharge. The emitter voltage is pinned to Vcc, and you're never driving the base higher than that to allow it to turn on.
The standard analysis for an emitter follower, and for most linear BJT circuits in general, assumes that the transistor is in forward-active mode for the entire cycle. Your transistor is never in forward-active mode at all.


how can I predict the emitter voltage or current?

Generally, you'd do it by solving the differential equation system that models the circuit. SPICE does it numerically. You may be able to come up with an approximate closed-form solution by normalizing the component values and operating frequency to 1 or another convenient value, solving it numerically, fitting a function to the result, and rescaling the function back to the original circuit's component values and frequency of operation.
